# AXIOS POST in vue not working: Suggestions?

Tags: vue.js, express, axios

I'm trying to get a sign up feature. I have used expressjs to make the backend POST method that looks like this:

```js
export const insertUser = (data, result) => {
    db.query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ?", [data], (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            result(err, null);
        } else {
            result(null, results);
        }
    });
}
```

I then have a frontend where I use axios to post the values into the database, as this:

```js
async insertUser() {
      try {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users", {
          first_name: this.first_name,
          second_name: this.second_name,
          email: this.email,
          road: this.road,
          town: this.town,
          post_code: this.post_code,
          user_name: this.username,
          password: this.password,
        });
        this.first_name = "";
        this.second_name = "";
        this.email = "";
        this.road = "";
        this.town = "";
        this.post_code = "";
        this.username = "";
        this.password = "";
        this.$router.push("/");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
```

However, I have used postman to try and post the information but I get an error saying that INSERT INTO users VALUES is incorrect. I have triple checked everything but for the life of me can't see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

seem's the problem is in the nodejs function

```
"INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?)"
```

for each data you need to put an '?' in the values
also if you have an id in our database that is auto increment you need to specify columns to update

```
"INSERT INTO users(name,email) VALUES (?,?)"
```

i think your data is an array no need to put it in brackets just : ,data,

Comment: ok so it kind of works, except when it adds the information, it sets them to the number 0 in the database. It's so weird.

Comment: maybe the type of data in database  and are you sure you don't send null data inside your array?

Comment: Well, in VSCode in the backend terminal is shows the data that it's sending and its exactly what I inputed on the frontend, however when it gets to the database it gives it the value 0

Comment: make sure you send the correct variable to the database model maybe something like : insertUser(req.body.data)